# Finding the coefficient of determination from a regression line?

Tags: regression, linear, r-squared

Suppose you are given the following estimated model from a sample of size 1217:

$\hat{y} = 1.177663 + 0.0910103x$

and the standard errors of the coefficients are $0.0865446$ and $0.0065643$ respectively. How do you determine the coefficient of determination ($R^2$)?

If I had ${\sigma}_y$, I think I could easily solve this using the fact that $\hat{\beta} = r_{x, y}\frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}$. Is there another formula that I should be looking into?

Comment: Start by writing formulas for the two standard errors, $R^2,$ and the coefficient estimates.  The rest is algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering whuber's comment, we use the fact that:

\begin{equation}\label{eq1}R^2 = \frac{SSR}{SST} = \frac{\sum^{n}_{i=1}(\hat{y}_i - \bar{y})^2}{\sum^{n}_{i=1}e^2_i + \sum^{n}_{i=1}(y_i - \bar{y})^2}\end{equation}

We know that $\hat{\alpha} = \bar{y} - \hat{\beta}\bar{x}$, thus $\hat{y}_i - \bar{y} = \hat{\beta}(x_i - \bar{x})$. The formula for the variance of $\hat{\beta}$ is: \begin{equation}\label{eq2}Var(\hat{\beta}) = \frac{s^2}{\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i - \bar{x})^2} = \frac{\sum^n_{i=1}e_i^2}{(n-2)\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i - \bar{x})^2}\end{equation}

Using $\hat{y}_i - \bar{y}$ and eq (2) on eq (1), we will get:
\begin{equation}
R^2 = \frac{\hat{\beta}^2\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i - \bar{x})^2}{Var(\hat{\beta})(n-2)\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i - \bar{x})^2+\hat{\beta}^2\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i - \bar{x})^2} = \frac{\hat{\beta}^2}{Var(\hat{\beta})(n-2)+\hat{\beta}^2}
\end{equation}

In our case, $R^2 \approx 0.13 $.